# AttributeConverter fails after publishing to wildfly 9.0.2

Tags: java, jpa, converters, wildfly, wildfly-9

I have an entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import br.com.fidellibre.utils.Suporte;

@Entity
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SQ_CLIE_SQ_CLIENTE", sequenceName = "SQ_CLIE_SQ_CLIENTE", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SQ_CLIE_SQ_CLIENTE")
    @Column(name = "CLIE_SQ_CLIENTE")
    private long codigo;

    @Column
    private String nome;

    @Column
    private String login;

    @Column
    private String celular;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String codigoGmail;

    @Column
    private String codigoTwitter;

    @Column
    private String codigoFacebook;

    @Column
    private String codigoAparelho;

    @Column(name = "CLIE_DT_ULTIMO_ACESSO") 
    private LocalDateTime ultimoAcesso;

    @Column
    private String senha;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cliente")
    private List<Conta> contas;
...
}
```

and a `Converter`:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;


@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {
    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime date) {
        return date == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(date);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp dbData) {
        return dbData == null ? null : dbData.toLocalDateTime();
    }

}
```

This works fine in my unit test, persisting in database.

But on wildfly 9 the same code crashes... :(

Just by modifying  the class, anotating with `@Converter`  like this:

```
@Column(name = "CLIE_DT_ULTIMO_ACESSO",columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP")
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime ultimoAcesso;
```

So whats the point of having the `autoApply` property if it doesn't work all times? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, to add some more information, I'm using java 1.8, jpa 2.1, hibernate 5.0

Comment: Is there a stack trace with the crash?